# left of [fill in the blank] must have class/struct/union error

Tags: c++

So I have this line:

```
ArrayList<Operation> operations();
```

Now, this is my ArrayList class and my Operation struct:

```
typedef struct Operation {
    char key; 
    int value;
} Operation;
template <class DT>
class ArrayList
{
private:
    int _capacity;
    int _size;
    DT* elements;
public:
    ArrayList();
    ~ArrayList();
    void insert (DT&);
    DT& operator[] (int);
};
ArrayList<DT>::ArrayList()
{
    _capacity = 10;
    _size = 0;
    elements = new DT[10];
}
```

I don't see the need of posting the code of the other methods since the error isn't happening there. However if you want to see them you just have to ask.

Now, everytime I try to do something like

```
operations.insert(x) //assuming x is a struct that exists.
```

or

```
operations[i].key; //assuming i is a declared and initialized index.
```

It gives me the `error C2228: left of (fill in the blank) must have class/struct/union`
and `error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type`

I have seen a previous thread about this problem and I think my problem is that the compiler takes the first line of code I provided as a declaration, but no initialization.
However I didn't see a solution for this. In my head the only solution is to make it a pointer and use `= new ...` but in my head the keyword `new` is synonym of nastiness so I simply wanted to make it a an object. What is a way to go around this?
Or perhaps I am wrong, and this has something to do with the object type being a `struct` since this is the first time I work with `struct`s.

Comment: I love the Most Vexing Parse. Search that term and you'll find 500 duplicates.

Comment: While you don't need to provide all code, the actual declaration of `operations` in both examples **is** important.

Comment: @chris yup, and I read a bunch of them, but hardly saw the answer I needed.

Comment: @Yokhen, Yes, I guess realizing that it's a function is enough, as it's just accidental usually. I guess not knowing how to default-construct it is a bit different than every one I've seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
ArrayList<Operation> operations();
```

Declares a function that returns an `ArrayList<Operation>`

This is commonly referred to as [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

To declare your `ArrayList<Operation>`, remove the parenthesis:

```
ArrayList<Operation> operations;
```

Comment: I know, so how can I initialize it with the default constructor? Which is what I meant to do, not just declare it.

Comment: Whoa, Magic! All the errors went away. Thanks a lot. Although the only one, the best answer :D

Comment: This is not an example of the most vexing parse. It's simply a function declaration. Changing the parsing rules to eliminate the most vexing parse would not change this. Look more carefully at the example in the link.