# Can't assign value in 3d map unless constructing at the same time

Tags: c++, class, stl, dictionary, constructor

I'm trying to create a 3 dimensional map containing a non-stl class I've created.  The compiler fails whenever I try to assign an instantiated variable (I believe to be in the stack) to the map.

It works if I perform:

```
volume[x][y][z] = Chunk()
```

but not if I perform:

```
Chunk c();
volume[x][y][z] = c;
```

Here's a short example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

class Chunk {
public:
    Chunk();
    Chunk(const Chunk& orig);
    virtual ~Chunk();
};

Chunk::Chunk(){

}

Chunk::Chunk(const Chunk& orig) {
}

Chunk::~Chunk() {
}

/*
 *
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    map<uint32_t, map<uint32_t, map<uint32_t, Chunk > > > volume;
    int32_t width = 5, height = 5, depth = 5;
    for(uint32_t x = 0; x < width; x++){
        for(uint32_t y = 0; y < height; y++){
            for(uint32_t z = 0; y < depth; y++){
                Chunk c();
                volume[x][y][z] = c;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This example gives the following compile error:

```
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:41:35: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘(&(& volume.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Key = unsigned int, _Tp = std::map<unsigned int, std::map<unsigned int, Chunk> >, _Compare = std::less<unsigned int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::map<unsigned int, std::map<unsigned int, Chunk> > > >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = std::map<unsigned int, std::map<unsigned int, Chunk> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = unsigned int]((*(const key_type*)(& x))))->std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Key = unsigned int, _Tp = std::map<unsigned int, Chunk>, _Compare = std::less<unsigned int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::map<unsigned int, Chunk> > >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = std::map<unsigned int, Chunk>, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = unsigned int]((*(const key_type*)(& y))))->std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Key = unsigned int, _Tp = Chunk, _Compare = std::less<unsigned int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, Chunk> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = Chunk, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = unsigned int]((*(const key_type*)(& z))) = c’
main.cpp:41:35: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:14:7: note: Chunk& Chunk::operator=(const Chunk&)
main.cpp:14:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Chunk()’ to ‘const Chunk&’
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sean/NetBeansProjects/test3dmap'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sean/NetBeansProjects/test3dmap'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 213ms)
```

I suspect I may have to instead create a 3d map like follows:

```
map<uint32_t, map<uint32_t, map<uint32_t, Chunk* > > > volume;
```

but then I will have to perform memory management in my own code which I'd like to avoid.  How do I get the map example shown to work?

Comment: See my answer to this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615292/left-of-fill-in-the-blank-must-have-class-struct-union-error/13615318#comment18669793_13615318

Comment: C++ compiler messages can be most *un*helpful, but in this case, the specific line within all your errors viz., `main.cpp:14:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Chunk()’ to ‘const Chunk&’` is the one that should give you a clue as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Chunk c();` is a function declaration. Try `Chunk c;`.

P.S. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse (as pointed in Chad's answer in the link above this is not quite the same but also good to know).

Answer (score 1):

See the C++ FAQ.  Matrices are better developed using `()` than `[]`.
Here's the link: [C++ FAQ: Matrix operator overloading](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/matrix-subscript-op.html)